# Object Web, visit classes that are passed as parameter class value

Tags: java, java-bytecode-asm

I want to visit classes that are passed in a method

I tried `visitMethodInsn` in my `MethodVisitor` but I get the method signature, not the class passed when it’s executed

public static class C {
    }

```
public static class B {
    void myMethod(Class clz) {
    }
}
public static class A {
    static B getB() {
        return new B();
    }
}

public static class Foo {
    public Foo() {
        A.getB().myMethod(C.class);
    }
}
```

So based on the code above, when visiting the `Foo` class I want to be noticed that `C.class` is being passed to `myMethod` in `B.class`

Comment: This is not trivial, as this statement is not compiled to a single instruction. There's an `LDC` instruction pushing the value for `C.class` to the operand stack and an `invokevirtual` instruction targeting `myMethod`, which will pop the receiver and arguments from the stack. You have to trace the effect of the instructions on the stack to predict which actual value will be passed to a method.  You may use [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48806265/2711488) as a starting point, to write code which checks the arguments to an invocation instruction instead of load instruction.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. Finally I managed to get that by using the  `visitLdcInsn` in the `MethodVisitor` implementation returned when my class visitor visits `myMethod`.